# MVC Redirect to a different view in another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, redirecttoaction

After a user has completed a form in MVC and the post action is underway, I am trying to redirect them back to another view within another model.

Eg.  This form is a sub form of a main form and once the user has complete this sub form I want them to go back to the main form.

I thought the following might have done it, but it doesn't recognize the model...

```
//send back to edit page of the referral
return RedirectToAction("Edit", clientViewRecord.client);
```

Any suggestions are more that welcome...

Comment: Please add to your question your class for model, action "Edit" and error, what you receiving

Comment: RedirectToAction wont help if you are sending an async post request from browser. You need to send json data from server and handle it in the callback function on client side.

Comment: Please provide more information. Are you posting via JavaScript & jQuery, or using something like `@Html.BeginForm`, is the model you're trying to refer too bound to the type of what you're passing in, are you attempting redirects or directing to URL's in JavaScript or using a tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it the way you are doing it.  You are trying to pass a complex object in the url, and that just doesn't work.  The best way to do this is using route values, but that requires you to build the route values specifically.  Because of all this work, and the fact that the route values will be shown on the URL, you probably want this to be as simple a concise as possible.  I suggest only passing the ID to the object, which you would then use to look up the object in the target action method.

For instance:

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", new {id = clientViewRecord.client.ClientId});
```

The above assumes you at using standard MVC routing that takes an id parameter. and that client is a complex object and not just the id, in which case you'd just use `id = clientViewRecord.client`

Answer (score 0):

A redirect is actually just a simple response. It has a status code (302 or 307 typically) and a `Location` response header that includes the URL you want to redirect to. Once the client receives this response, they will typically, then, request that URL via GET. Importantly, that's a brand new request, and the client will not include any data with it other than things that typically go along for the ride by default, like cookies.

Long and short, you cannot redirect with a "payload". That's just not how HTTP works. If you need the data after the redirect, you must persist it in some way, whether that be in a database or in the user's session.

Comment: Actually, yes.  You can redirect with a payload, but not in the way the OP is doing it.  You can pass route values as part of the redirect, and a suitable url/querystring will be created for the url.

Comment: The query string is not a payload; it's part of the URI. While, yes, you may be able to bastardize it somewhat to pass some data along, it's totally inappropriate to do so. Additionally, the OP hasn't given much info about what the data *is*, but given it's related to a client, it may very well contain sensitive information you would not want in a URL.

Comment: Agreed, but I just wanted to make it clear that it *is* possible to pass data in a redirect, but as I said in my answer that this should just be something simple like a client id.

Answer (score 0):

If your intending to redirect to an action with the model. I could suggest using the tempdata to pass the model to the action method.

```
TempData["client"] = clientViewRecord.client;    
return RedirectToAction("Edit");


public ActionResult Edit ()
{
 if (TempData["client"] != null)
            {
               var client= TempData["client"] as Client ;
               //to do...
            }    
}
```

Comment: Actually, TempData is a poor choice for this, because it's a one-time access.  This means if the user presses F5 to refresh the page after redirection, the data is gone.